# Whats the sample frequency of iPhones velocimeter?

Tags: ios, iphone, signal-processing, sample-rate

I'm developing an iOS app that needs precision velocimeter data capturing. For that i need to know what are the maximum sample frequency of iOS devices velocimeters. Couldn't find that on devices especifications or anywhere.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

So the speed gets calculated from distance and time, there is not a real frequency.

The CLLocation speed attribute gets updated every time your device is moving.

It means, even when you looking for the object every millisecond, you only get the last calculated coordinate.

**Update**

https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1423500-distancefilter

This distance is measured relative to the previously delivered location. Use the value kCLDistanceFilterNone to be notified of all movements. The default value of this property is kCLDistanceFilterNone.
This property is used only in conjunction with the standard location services and is not used when monitoring significant location changes.

So I think this means, that the frequency is depending on the gps signal it self.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GPS_signals

Comment: sure, but what is the frequancy that the device updates? Like, if i change my speed 4 times on a milllisecond, will it get updates 4 times?